# You do not have permission to view this directory or page Azure and FTP (Filezilla error)

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I am getting the following error message when I try to view an azure website I created: 'You do not have permission to view this directory or page.'

When I click on the URL I created in Microsoft Azure, it also disconnects me from the FTP that I have set up with this error messsage: 'Disconnected from server: ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted'  I thought I fixed this setting by going into Filezilla FTP Settings and changing it from Passive to Active

I don't know if these things are related to each other or causing one of the things to happen, but I don't understand what to do or what is broken?

Update:  I got the error message 'You do not have permission to view this directory or page.' to work by changing the name of my html file from 'index2.html' to 'index.html' but it isn't playing my html file correctly.  It has changed into a small black box, rather than filling up the whole screen and it is just a black box with a play button, but it doesn't play.[Azure website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpuDL.png)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.  I uploaded my video to Wistia and then added the Inline Embed code to my index.html file, then added my files to Filezilla, and then the hosting site from Azure finally worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am glad you fixed the issue. If you see the issue again, could you please restart the website and check once.

For testing/debugging purposes you can turn on the Azure detailed messaging, and turn back off when its ready for production. To do so, you have to follow these two steps,

Login to Azure > App Services (left side menu) > Your Web App > Diagnostics logs (search box is at the top if you can't find it), then turn on Detailed Error Messages or turn on all of the loging options, up to you.
Now add the following in your Web Config file,
In your Web Config file add  BEFORE system.web closing tag, . Similarly, add  BEFORE . Finally, upload the Web Config to Azure and cross your fingers.
If you follow the steps correctly, that will show the error messages in detail and hopefully from there